# Is it appropriate for a teacher to make a sex analogy related to physics?

Tags: etiquette, physics

My physics professor was talking about the companion forces that act on an object with molecules interacting with one another and Newton's 3rd law canceling out the internal forces. Then he said something like “do you have to put all the little forces? No it’s not necessary, but you can. This will be a bit unsettling but your parents may tell you “don’t have sex” or else you may have to deal with a child and other stuff. But it’s like you can, but you’ll have to consider the consequences. So it’s not like “don’t do it” but you can, but consider the consequences” (it was much longer than this but this is the jist)

It felt like an analogy that could've easily been replaced for something more appropriate. It kind of threw me off center and felt irrelevant. Was this comment appropriate for him to make?

Answer (score 10):

I don't know that I'd characterize this as a "sex analogy" per se but it doesn't seem to be either useful nor particularly vulgar, it seems like a poor attempt at humor and the reference is really to prohibitions by authority rather than about sexual activity, besides acknowledging the mechanism by which humans reproduce and the tendency of parents to want their kids to plan their reproduction.

If you were the instructor asking, I'd say drop it: risk that it's taken the wrong way for little to no benefit.

As the student asking, I'd recommend just forgetting about it. If you have an opportunity for anonymous feedback you could mention it made you feel uncomfortable.

Comment: It probably was a poor attempt at humour. I agree with your answer, BTW, and upvoted. One needs to be very careful these days with jokes. They say the only safe jokes to make these days is about oneself and about lawyers. And I wait for the moment when the latter will be the matter of lawsuits, too. And, when that happens, of course, there is not a chance of a snowflake in Death Valley to win that one.